How to view HTTP headers for HTTP-triggered Azure functions?
I have an Azure Function app with several HTTP-triggered functions.
Each request is logged to a Log Analytics workspace, in a table called AppRequests, with limited information about the request, like the HttpMethod and ResultCode.
Is there any way to inspect the HTTP headers, like the Origin etc.?


Do you want to inspect the headers in Application Insights?

What is the Runtime stack of your function app?

@PravallikaKV By runtime stack you mean .NET isolated?

Application Insights is based on the information in the Log Analytics workspace, right? So, if the information is not there, it won't be in Application Insights either?

You can add foreach (var header in req.Headers)  {      _logger.LogInformation($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");  } in your function code. This will log the Http headers in Application insights.

Check my answer below @Shuzheng

Add below code snippet in your function code to log and view the Http headers in Application Insights.
 foreach (var header in req.Headers)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");
 }

Function.cs:
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        foreach (var header in req.Headers)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");
        }
        return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
    }
}

Application Logs in Portal:
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=87ef3960-f6f1-433d-978b-08b523508a25)
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Accept: application/json
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Host: rkfn.azurewebsites.net
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Cache-Control: no-cache
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Content-Type: application/json
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Correlation-Context: %23AzFuncLiveLogsSessionId=451d4e1f-18e9-4c40-83f1-f9fddd2d9686
//Removed few logs
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   X-Original-URL: /api/Function1
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /api/Function1
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   DISGUISED-HOST: rkfn.azurewebsites.net
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   x-ms-invocation-id: 87ef3960-f6f1-433d-978b-08b523508a25
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   X-Original-Proto: http
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   X-Original-Host: localhost:50485
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   X-Original-For: 127.0.0.1:50659
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
2024-12-17T15:35:50Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=87ef3960-f6f1-433d-978b-08b523508a25, Duration=256ms)

Able to see the Headers under FunctionApp=>Application Insights=>Logs:

